# Is it possible to use Crystal Reports 2008 with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project with Crystal Reports 2008 (dotNET 3.5). I want to work on it with Visual Studio 2017. Is it possible?

I already tried to

1- open it and saying no to upgrade process for the Crystal Reports still end up using Crystal Reports 21 (the one that compatible with VS2017) references.

2- remove Crystal Reports 21 references and add 2008 manually, VS told me "could not be added please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is valid assembly or COM component".

So, can I still use the old Crystal Reports with VS17. If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an answer like me, yes you can, if you don't upgrade you can still work with it but you can't edit it until you upgrade to  version 13.
Also you can use it with .NET Framework 4 but you have to install both Crystal Reports 10 and 13 runtimes for it to work on the client machine or upgrade the reports to 13 and install 13 only.